# Different Google Index Information

Tags: google-search-console, google-index

More or less three month ago, I launched my own website. On the first day, I also verified my website for the Google Webmaster Tools, combined them with the Google Analytics Account and submitted a sitemap index file linked to five sitemap files.

But till now, I receive different Google Index Status information:

In Webmaster Tools:

- Menu: Crawl -> Sitemaps: 123,861 Urls submitted, 64,313 Urls indexed
- Menu: Google Index -> Index Status: 65,375 Urls indexed

When I type in google.de: “site:www.mysite.de”, then I receive 103,000 results.

When I check my website with push2check.net, I receive 110,000 Urls in Google Index.

What is wrong there? I understand that’s impossible for Google to deliver the accurate date because of the distributed processing and the result also depends on the location, where you searching from and so on. But between 65,000 and 110,000 is a huge gap. What’s the reason?

Thanks in advance!

Toby

Comment: There might be duplicate urls in the search result list (SERP) in your google search. Also the SERP numbers are "estimates" so to speak, because it doesn't calculate the exact number to display (so 103000 might cover a different number specifically). 
Also the urls in their index aren't necessarily shown in the SERP due to duplications, rank or other factors. But the difference between indexed urls in the two menu items, I don't have any plausible explanation for.

Answer (score 0):

```
google.de: “site:www.mysite.de”
```

You can search this type then google view your site all pages display index by Google.

And

Only Search

> push2check.net

Then google View all result display when your website link have.

Then both result is different.